# Turn off Silverlight in CuteWebUI.AjaxUploader

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

Hey I am using the CuteWebUI AjaxUploader which works great but we have seen for certain users using IE7 the first time they use the uploader they are prompted to install Silverlight, and they are saying that even after installing Silverlight they are prompted again to install.

1) Is silverlight required ?
2) Can it be switched off ?

Thanks in advance
Steven

Answer (score 1):

To disable Silverlight in CuteWebUI AjaxUploader, use uploader advanced options:

```
protected void CuteUploader_Init(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // CuteUploader - your uploader control id
    CuteUploader.SetAdvancedOption(UploaderAdvancedOption.NoSilverlight, "true");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To disable Silverlight in CuteWebUI AjaxUploader, use uploader advanced options:

```
  protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
  {
      Uploader1.SetAdvancedOption(UploaderAdvancedOption.NoSilverlight, "true");
      base.OnLoad(e);
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You should set **UploadType="IFrame"** to resolve this.